# When and how to add an Available on the App Store badge to my iphone app presentation site?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'll release an app in a few days, but one thing I wonder is this:

1) How and when do I get that special link to the App Store?

2) Any way to set up that badge shortly after submitting the app? Or must I first wait until it's approved and published on the store, then search for it on iTunes and then copy the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will send you a URL via e-mail when they accept the app.  The URL will take visitors directly to your app.  You should put the link up then.

Answer (score 1):

If your developer name or app name are sufficiently unique, there are URL patterns you can use. I'm not sure how it handles multiple apps with identical names once special characters and whitespace are removed, though.

- http://itunes.com/ArtistOrDeveloperName
- http://itunes.com/app/AppName

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is a "View in Appstore" link in iTunes Connect that will start working once the app hits the store. It's there before (once you submit it, as far as I remember), it just does not show the app. Still it is the correct link.